# VMware VCenter performance

Tags: java, memory, vmware

I am trying to figure out why our VMware VCenter server is consuming so much CPU and memory.
I noticed that there are a couple of java process running on the server that are consuming a substantial amount of RAM memory.

The VCenter server is virtual and running Windows Server 2008 with 8GB RAM.

Does anyone know what these java processes are belonging to?

[image: Java processes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the vCenter core services use java, so it is almost certainly related to vCenter's services.

Your best bet to determine what each process is for is to use a better tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  It will show you the process tree indicating which parent process spawned it, and will also explicitly list out the services associated with the process by hovering over the process name.

However, if you want to check directly from the command line, you can use something like this:

```
TASKLIST /SVC /FI "IMAGENAME EQ JAVA.EXE"
```

- The `/SVC` flag tells the system to list out running services.
- The `/FI` flag states you wish to filter results using specified criteria
- `"IMAGENAME EQ JAVA.EXE"` is the filter to list only process with an image name of "JAVA.EXE"

Answer (score 2):

TASKLIST /SVC /FI "IMAGENAME EQ JAVA.EXE"

This will not get you the processes running within Java. Nor will Process Explorer. Java is a virtual machine environment. Its a container. It actually doesn't run any processes. It executes IL. Intermediate Language. Its what Java is (and .NET) are compiled down in to. Its the equivalent to the CLR in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

In Task Manager select view, then columns and "command line" 
It should provide further information as to what Java is running.